# jQuery UI drag and drop between DIVs, smoothing

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have become interested in [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) libraries for the benefits they provide over a pure JavaScript programming practise.

I am trying to implement [a drag and drop GUI for my hobby site](http://www.guygar.com/eXistenZ/index.html).

```
$('#artOfBeing').draggable ({ 
    containment: '#dataFrame', 
    cursor: 'pointer', 
    snap: '#dataFrame', 
    helper: 'clone' 
});
    
$('#dataFrame').droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent   
});
```

I already see benefits of jQuery regarding how easy it was to provide a great method of cloning for the menubar icons on the right (to be dragged to the destination drop div).

When I select the top most icon of the menubar on the right vertical with a mouse; any kind of movement triggers the drag and drop operation. The icon jumps to the containment #div (without a transition animation crossing between the divs (source and destination).

I would to like achieve a smooth transition between the time when I select the icon and moving it to the drop div instead of a straight jump into the content mr. monkey div.

I would also like some information regarding the **cancel** of a drag and drop operation under way.

Please provide tips regarding how best to learn these issues of jQuery libraries.

**EDIT:** The solution provided Nabab below has some strange effects. Firstly I get different results depending if I am checking it on a local machine or downloading from the web-host server.

In local tests IE9 functions well and the icon drag is limited to the containment DIV which houses both drag and drop divs. Local execution by FF or Chrome and the results are weird, the drag item behaves strangly.

Online web-server and all of them behave the same way. The containment div is ignored and I can drag the icon whereever I like on the screen which is functional but I would like to constrain the drag within the content and nav divs.

Any ideas as to why such behaviour is taking place?

Comment: As far as I know, between local and online server the difference can only come from the cookies, the browser cache, the files' path, or the files themselves (i.e. different between local & server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a containment, it'd be more logical to have your source inside this containement. Why don't you wrap the central space + the buttons space in a DIV which would become the containment. Performing an animation would be very tough as the position of the item depends on the mouse (which drags it), and if your source is outside the container, I cannot imagine how it would perform this transition...

Comment: This solution seems to work in IE9! But in FF or Safari is not working! Sorry to demote your answer. Look forward to further advise! Thanks.

Comment: I rechecked by flushing the cache completely for all the browsers and now it is working everywhere. You indeed deserve the credit.

Comment: Thanks also as this approach does not need a Cancel operation. The right event occures only when dropped on the drop div. simple!

Comment: I am faced with some other issues related to this matter and I am including them in my original post as a Edit.

Comment: Then somehow it fell apart again... :( same issues with FF, Safari and Chrome. any help from any is most welcome.

Comment: you advise is sound.. i think it is a layout issue that i have to work through.

Comment: yeah, some CSS was not sound. now it works fully. thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Oops, sorry, discovering all your messages now! Glad it helped